# Android GUI design: how to fill white edges

Tags: android

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="rjbc.emergencytext.EmergencyText"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
>




  <LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="92dp"
   android:layout_weight="0.07"
   android:background="#044ff2"></LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

How can i fill the white spaces with this linear layout? I cant seem to adjust the layout anymore. thank you

*here is the whole code

Comment: Remove all padding.

Answer (score 0):

Take off the 4 padding parameters at your parent Linear Layout. It will set the padding from your parent Linear Layout to zero, and no more white spaces.

Padding is the empty space inside of a View. Your parent layout covers the whole screen, but got some space for the inside.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't even have reputation to comment, just trying to help.

Comment: Please wait until you have at-least 50 or such answers will be flagged and down-voted by community during review.

Answer (score 0):

You have one linear layout nested inside another linear layout. Problem is that you have added extra padding in the parent layout and set the width of the child layout to `match_parent`. This takes whole width as taken by the parent layout. Solution is just remove the padding arguments for the `top`, `left` or `right` or as according to your needs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

remove this attribute from your parent linearlayout

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

due to this padding you getting this white space.